# Errors on magento installation

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

After installing Magento, and without errors on importing the database, I get some weird errors on front end http://metalhouse.devpassion.eu/:

```
There has been an error processing your request
The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded

Trace:
#0 /home/kiwikiwi/public_html/metalhouse/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(247): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->setFetchMode(2)
#1 /home/kiwikiwi/public_html/metalhouse/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(165): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->__construct(Array)
#2 /home/kiwikiwi/public_html/metalhouse/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#3 /home/kiwikiwi/public_html/metalhouse/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_read')
#4 /home/kiwikiwi/public_html/metalhouse/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('read')
#5 /home/kiwikiwi/public_html/metalhouse/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(355): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#6 /home/kiwikiwi/public_html/metalhouse/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection()
#7 /home/kiwikiwi/public_html/metalhouse/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#8 /home/kiwikiwi/public_html/metalhouse/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1386): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#9 /home/kiwikiwi/public_html/metalhouse/app/Mage.php(460): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#10 /home/kiwikiwi/public_html/metalhouse/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#11 /home/kiwikiwi/public_html/metalhouse/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#12 /home/kiwikiwi/public_html/metalhouse/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(602): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#13 /home/kiwikiwi/public_html/metalhouse/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(460): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#14 /home/kiwikiwi/public_html/metalhouse/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#15 /home/kiwikiwi/public_html/metalhouse/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 /home/kiwikiwi/public_html/metalhouse/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}
```

Comment: Seems like the same problem as described in this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386575/the-pdo-extension-is-required-for-this-adapter-but-the-extension-is-not-loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Checking requirements

In order to run Magento your server needs to meet some basic software requirements. It sounds like you've not got PHP configured with PDO enabled.

You can test your server for compatibility by following these simple steps:

1. Download the [magento-check](http://www.magentocommerce.com/_media/magento-check.zip) file to your computer and unzip it.
2. Upload the extracted magento-check.php file to the Magento directory on your server
3. In your browser navigate to this page `/magento-check.php`

#### Installing PDO

You can install it fairly easily via command line

```
pecl install pdo_mysql
```

Then after the installation is complete, be sure to add this to your `php.ini` and restart Apache/Nginx etc.

```
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento work with database during PDO. On your server this module is not installed. Or not activated on PHP.

Make file with phpinfo() and check this. If PDO not installed, then contact with your system administrator or hosting support and ask fix this problem.