# PDO loads fine in Magento but not in external CMS

Tags: php, magento, pdo, magento-1.7

I am having a problem similar to [The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386575/the-pdo-extension-is-required-for-this-adapter-but-the-extension-is-not-loaded) but not the same.

The Magento install is running fine but when I try to run:

```
require_once(APATH.MAGEPATH.'/app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();
```

in a directory outside of Magento I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with message 'The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded' in
/home/inzana/public_html/Store/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:342 
Stack trace: #0 /home/inzana/public_html/Store/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(247): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->setFetchMode(2) 
#1 /home/inzana/public_html/Store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(165): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->__construct(Array) 
#2 /home/inzana/public_html/Store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element)) 
#3 /home/inzana/public_html/Store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write') 
#4 /home/inzana/public_html/Store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write') 
#5 /home/inzana/public_html/Store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/R in /home/inzana/public_html/Store/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 342
```

phpinfo() reports:

```
'./configure' '--disable-fileinfo' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-mbstring' 
'--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-sockets' '--prefix=/usr' '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' '--with-gd' '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' '--with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre' 
'--with-pdo-mysql=shared' 
'--with-pdo-sqlite=shared' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-sqlite=shared' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr'
```

The local php.ini file includes:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

I am a loss of where to go next.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mkaatman This is not a Magento specific issue. It's on-topic on Stack Overflow - actually even more so than on Magento.SE

Comment: How are you calling the second script?

Comment: We have a proprietary CMS (similar to Code Igniter) that we build from I am working on a magento model for it.  So basically I have a test controller that loads the model and this code is in the public function __construct() of the model.

Comment: I just verified that it is using the local php.ini file and it is.

Comment: I added phpinfo(INFO_GENERAL); above the call to the module.  The page is at http://inzanaranch.com/test if you want to take a look.  Let me know if you need any other parts of phpinfo dumped out.

Comment: Magento is version 1.7.0.2.

Comment: Hey I am facing a similar issue...wondering if you figured out a solution for it and what it was

Answer (score 0):

**Checking pdo extension installed or not**

```
echo 'Checking pdo extension installed or not';
echo '<pre/>';
extension_loaded ('PDO' ); // returns boolean
```

// or

```
extension_loaded('pdo_mysql');
```

// or get all extensions and search for a specific one

```
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());  exit();
```

If installed then show in print result array like below

```
[41] => PDO    [42] => pdo_sqlite    [43] => pdo_mysql
```