# how to fix this error in magento?

Tags: magento

```
a:4:{i:0;s:78:"The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded";i:1;s:1536:"#0 /home/fnmvhnvj/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(247): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->setFetchMode(2)
#1 /home/fnmvhnvj/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(165): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->__construct(Array)
#2 /home/fnmvhnvj/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#3 /home/fnmvhnvj/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#4 /home/fnmvhnvj/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#5 /home/fnmvhnvj/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#6 /home/fnmvhnvj/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Config.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#7 /home/fnmvhnvj/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Config->loadToXml(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config))
#8 /home/fnmvhnvj/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(260): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadDb()
#9 /home/fnmvhnvj/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(270): Mage_Core_Model_Config->init(Array)
#10 /home/fnmvhnvj/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->init('', 'store', Array)
#11 /home/fnmvhnvj/public_html/index.php(80): Mage::init()
#12 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Comment: Just fixed it this problem/bug

Comment: Upvoted to get you back to 0 :D

Comment: Also make sure the MySQL username and password are correct inside of `app/etc/local.xml`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure you have a php.ini file with the following lines near the bottom:

**Code:**

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

If you don't already have this file, go to cPanel -> Software/Services -> PHP Config -> Install php.ini master file. You may also want to set your account to use the "PHP5 (single php.ini)" option under PHP Config.

If those steps don't help, I would try getting in contact with support since they seem to have had some problems Refer [LINK](http://www.bluehostforum.com/showthread.php?t=15308)

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: have you check is there any public_html level php.ini ?

Comment: pls refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386575/the-pdo-extension-is-required-for-this-adapter-but-the-extension-is-not-loaded

Comment: Install the PDO module for your database engine, using PECL. For example:

pecl install pdo
pecl install pdo_mysql

Comment: just fixed it by me

Issue in index.php file

Comment: Adding this directly in my public_html file to php.ini worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @gabearnoldm if my answer is useful to you.it should by upvote. :)

Answer (score 0):

As it is saying that the pdo extension is not loaded you should load pdo extension from php.ini

Answer (score 0):

We have used

extension=pdo.so

extension=pdo_mysql.so

extension=php_pdo.dll

extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll

It is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

To load the pdo.so and pdo_mysql.so in EasyApache (apache Update) use load you own profile and choose it from the  Exhaustive Options List
:-)